# Loading Image Gallery taking too time in Razor View

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I use a image gallery plugin called [Unite Gallery](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=default) plugin in an ASP.NET MVC project in order to display images stored in database. However, loading all of the images at the same time takes too long time (because each photo is in 1MB-4MB size and loading 500 photos at the same time on page load is not a good idea) and I think there must be a better approach i.e. asenkron loading or partial loading.  Here is my Razor and Controller code. I have a look at many pages on the wweb and docs, but there is not an example in the [documentation](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=documentation) page. Do you have any idea?

```
<div id="gallery" style="display:none;">        

    @foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.FileData != null)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.FileData);
            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);

            <img alt='Image'
                    src="@imgSrc"
                    data-image="@imgSrc"
                    data-description='Image'>
        }
    }
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    var gallery = jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
        gallery_theme: "default" //theme skin
    });

    gallery.on("item_change", function (num, data) {
        if((num%15) == 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@Url.Action("List", "PhotoContest")',
                data: { isAll: isAllChecked, page: num }, //??? I pass the page parameter???
              success: function(data){
                //call is successfully completed and we got result in data

                //??? NO IDEA ???

              },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                              //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error
                              alert(xhr.responseText);
                            }
              });
        }
    });

});

</script>


public ActionResult List(string query)
{
    var model = db.Photo.Select(m => new PhotoViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name,
        StatusId = m.StatusId,
        SubmitDate = m.SubmitDate,
        FileAttachments = m.FileAttachments,
        SubmitNo = m.SubmitNo
    })
    .ToArray();

    return View("List", model);
}
```

***Update:***

After trying to apply @Kris's perfect approach, I encountered the error shown below. There is not a fix or solution regarding to this specific problem on the web. Any idea?

[image]

The image after page load overloads div and gallery borders as shown below:

[image]

Comment: Hi @Clint Eastwood have a look at this [plugin](http://smallenvelop.com/display-loading-icon-page-loads-completely/)

Comment: Selam @mmushtaq, but this plugin seems to be related to page loading rather than image gallery.

Comment: WalaikumAslam. [Here](http://smallenvelop.com/demo/image-loading/) is its demo for image loading.

Comment: @mmushtaq Thanks a lot. What about an example via Image Gallery like [this](http://unitegallery.net/index.php?page=default)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Load 30 images at a time

> Load remaining in Itemchange event available in Unite gallery

Main Page

```
<div id="gallery" >
<input type="hidden" id="galleryPage" value="0"/>
@HTML.Action("GalleryImages") //first load 30 items as PageNo = 0
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
var gallery;
    jQuery(document).ready(function () {
    gallery = jQuery("#gallery").unitegallery({
        gallery_theme: "default" //theme skin
    });

    gallery.on("item_change", function (num, data) {
      //when item loaded equals to 15 or 30 or multiples of 15 another 30 items get loaded
        if((num%15) == 0)
        {
            $.ajax({
                url: '@HTML.Action("GalleryImages")'+"?pageNo="+jQuery("galleryPage").val(),
                data: { isAll: isAllChecked },
              success: function(data){
               jQuery("gallery").append(data);//partial view with new images
               jQuery("galleryPage").val(gallery.getNumItems()/30); //page number total items/number of items per page
              },
              error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                              //some errror, some show err msg to user and log the error
                              alert(xhr.responseText);
                            }
              });
        }
    });

});

</script>
```

Partial View (_galleryImages.cshtml)

```
@foreach (var item in Model)
    {
        if (item.FileData != null)
        {
            var base64 = Convert.ToBase64String(item.FileData);
            var imgSrc = String.Format("data:image/gif;base64,{0}", base64);

            <img alt='Image'
                    src="@imgSrc"
                    data-image="@imgSrc"
                    data-description='Image'>
        }
    }
```

Controller

```
 //Main View
    public ActionResult List()
    {
            return View();
    }

//Partial View
public Action GalleryImages(int PageNo)
{
    int PageSize = 30;
     var model = db.Photo.Select(m => new PhotoViewModel
    {
        Id = m.Id,
        Name = m.Name,
        StatusId = m.StatusId,
        SubmitDate = m.SubmitDate,
        FileAttachments = m.FileAttachments,
        SubmitNo = m.SubmitNo
    }).Skip(PageNo*PageSize).Take(PageSize).ToArray();

    return PartialView("_galleryImages", model);
}
```

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I tried to do this but I have no idea about the approach on how to get item number and how to load new data according to these info. Could you please post an example bu updating your answer? Regards....

Comment: Many thanks for your helps, voted+. On the other hand, there is a problem regarding to AJAX call. **1)** I use AJAX call as in the Update on my question. But I have no idea how to append the response (because I cannot watch on Firebug the response data and divs). **2)** I pass the page parameter as shown on update, but I do not understand num%15, numberofitems = 30 and skip(page*numberofitems). Could you please update the related AJAX section in your answer and clarify me about these issues?

Comment: Num%15 is to check whether the image is a multiple of 15 which make a new call for every 15 images. I will update the answer. Give me some time.right now I am writing from iPad and it's hard write everything but will do in next 30mins

Comment: Ok, no problem. You can answer until tomorrow morning :) Many many thanks for your kind helps... With the help of you I have learn a very important approach that will be used in lots of my future projects... Regards...

Comment: Hi Kris, sorry for disturbing. Just wanted to remind that I am waiting for your solution :) Many thanks again...

Comment: Sorry Chris, I saw later and tried to apply all the steps later. Then I encounter some errors as indicated on the last update in my question and tried to fix the problem in order not to spend your time much more. But unfortunately still the same error and there is no fix on the web regarding to this issue. On page load the images html seems to be created, but the image is too large and the gallery borders and buttons are not visible. I think the problem might be caused from the error above (update). Any idea?

Comment: @ClintEastwood is it in the first load or the next page loads ?

Comment: First load... On the other hand, when I try to fix the problem I comment out the lines causing to the problem on **ug-gallery.js** (line:668 > **if(itemType == "image"){..}** block. But at this time images are loaded on page load but another error occurs on console: **Unite Gallery Error: The slide don't have big image defined ( data-image='imageurl' ). Please check gallery items.**.

Comment: If you do not have time please let me know, I do not take your time much more. Because this is a specific problem and hard to fix without analyzing problem. But I understood the logic very well, many thanks for help and good explanations... Regards.

Comment: Just a secong: **<input type="hidden" id="galleryPage" value="0"/>** causing this errors.. I moved this line before gallery div and now trying to complete the solution. I will inform you asap.

Comment: I see that moving **<input type="hidden" id="galleryPage" value="0"/>** out of gallery div causing the **jQuery("#galleryPage").val()** value not being updated. The value always 0. On the other hand I needed to set PageNo value like @Html.Action("GalleryImages", new { pageNo = 0 }), otherwise encounter an error on this line. I think updating the  **jQuery("#galleryPage").val()** will fix the issue.

Comment: Moving it fixed the images issue ?

Comment: The hidden field is being updated in Ajax success so that shouldn't be a problem even you move it outside of div

Comment: Ok, I have fized many errors and now there is no console errors. However, although I can append the retrieved images, they cannot be seen in the Gallery. I used the following html string instead of data in order to see if it is visible after append to gallery div >>>

Comment: "<img alt=651413628 src = '/tr/PhotoContest/GetFile/13' data - description='No:651413628 1 Active  &lt;a title=&#39;Details&#39; href=&#39;/tr/PhotoContest/Details/5&#39;&gt;&lt;i class=&#39;fa fa-info-circle fa-lg&#39; aria-hidden=&#39;true&#39;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/a&gt;&lt;a title=&#39;Pasife al&#39; onclick=&#39;openPassiveModal(13, 1)&#39;&gt;&lt;/&gt;&lt;i class=&#39;fa fa-trash fa-lg&#39; aria-hidden=&#39;true&#39;&gt;&lt;/i&gt;&lt;/a&gt;' />";

Comment: I think the problem is related to appending the image divs to the wrong div. because the images are not listed under the gallery div. Any idea?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/139591/discussion-between-clint-eastwood-and-kris).

Comment: Although I have not managed to work it properly, I selected it as answer. I also looked a solution with fancBox3, but have not yet. Thanks a lot for your helps...

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's just one issue here. First, loading 100s of images all at once is going to be slow no matter what you do. For this point @Kris probably has the right idea. I'm unfamiliar with this particular library, but if it provides a way to progressively load in a handful of images at a time, you should definitely make use of that.

The second issue is that you're using base64-encoded data URIs. Images encoded in this way are roughly 150% as large as the actual image data itself. In other words, you're adding greater stress to an already stressed situation. Instead, you should have an action that returns the image data, something like:

```
public ActionResult GetImage(int id)
{
    var image = db.Images.Find(id);
    if (image == null)
    {
        return new HttpNotFoundResult();
    }

    return File(image.FileData, image.FileType);
}
```

You can get somewhat creative here by caching the database query result or even the entire response, but be advised that you'll need a significant amount of RAM, since you're going to be storing a lot of image data there.

Third, there's the issue of using a database to store image data in the first place. Just because databases provide a blob type, doesn't mean you need to use it. The most performant approach is always going to be serving directly from the filesystem, as IIS can serve static files directly, without involving all the ASP.NET machinery. Instead of storing the image data in your database, write the image to a filesystem location and then merely store the path to the image in the database. You could then optimize even further by actually offloading all the images to a CDN, ensuring super-fast delivery and taking virtually all load off your server.

Comment: You are definitely right about all of the issues you mentioned. **1)** I had already a method to get Images like your example, but I was not using it to display images. Using this method increased loading performance at least %60... **2)** I also tried to create a cache mechanism on database or IIS side, but I have not managed to implement such an approach (I use Entity Framework). So, is there an approach that I can use in order to make caching?

Comment: **3)** I had known that the file system was much more suitable for this scenario, but in case some problems on our System side, I generally avoid to use file system in case data loss. So, if I want to switch to File System, what changes should I make i.e. storing the file directory in the databse instead of file? As a result, many thanks for your perfect explanations as always you did and voted+...